# Discover the relation of two babies of a awkward marriage

Tags: family

There are two friends, they are not related. Each has a daughter. Their wives are dead.

Each man marries his friend's daughter, and after a while, both couples will have a child (a daughter).

What is the relationship between the two babies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The first baby would be a daughter of the daughter of the second man - his granddaughter.
   The second baby would be a daughter of the second man.
2. Therefore first baby is **niece** to the second baby. Similarly she is an **aunt** for the second baby.
3. Starting from this point one can find out that first baby is step-granddaughter for herself. Therefore first baby for the second baby is **step-great-granddaughter** and **step-great-great-great-granddaughter**, and step-great-great-great-great-great-granddaughter, **and so on**. The same is true for the first baby. Therefore first baby for the second baby is also **step-great-grandmother**, **step-great-great-great-grandmother** **and so on**. (But I'm not a native language speaker and not sure how correct it is to use here prefix "step" only one time per word.)

Comment: great and quick answer :

Comment: After one "grand", we use "great"s in English: father, grandfather, great-grandfather, [great-great-grandfather](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/great-great-grandfather), etc. I don't understand the relations here, so I'll let you fix it.

Comment: @TimS., thanks. You can't fully understand my answer?

Comment: I hadn't fully thought through the question. I think your answer is clear enough.